# Purpose of Webpack-Manifest-Plugin in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

In official doc says when applying `Code Splitting` and generating `chunk` files, if `chunk` code changes, then the filename of it will change. However `index.html` which uses the `chunk` code files can't change the filename in its `<script>` tag, so in this case the `manifest.json` which is generated by `webpack-manifest-plugin` will help mapping **`[name].js` to `[name].[hash].js`**.

But opposing to what the doc says, it seems that every time I run webpack to build my codes, new codes are generated with new hash value in its file(in case something in code changed), and `HTML-Webpack-Plugin` will autometically inject `<script>` tag with new name of code's file. This seems that there is no need to use `webpack-manifest-plugin`, I don't even see where the `manifest.json` is used.

In case if you are looking for my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./src/index.jsx"],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(`${__dirname}/build`)
  },
  mode: "none",
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',

    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules",
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'manifest.json'
    })
    // need this plugin for SSR?
  ]
}
```

What is the detailed usage of `webpack-manifest-plugin` and `manifest.json`?

Comment: There are a lot of cases where you want to use the result of a webpack build without being able to directly inject the script tags and need to know the final file name. I use it with ASP.Net Core to inject the script tags myself for example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

HtmlWebpackPlugin "knows" that your asset `bundle.js` maps to `bundle.some-hash.js` because it uses the Webpack's [Manifest](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#the-manifest). This manifest is not emitted though. It's just data that Webpack uses to keep track of how all the modules map to the output bundles.

[WebpackManifestPlugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) uses Webpack's manifest data data to emit a JSON file (that you can call `manifest.json` or whatever you want).

Since you are using HtmlWebpackPlugin with the [inject: true](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options) option (it's the default one), HtmlWebpackPlugin injects your bundle `bundle.some-hash.js` into your template. So you probably have no need to use WebpackManifestPlugin for your application.

If you did not use HtmlWebpackPlugin, or if you used it with `inject: false`, then you would need to find a way to "manually" inject the assets generated by Webpack.

So, the `manifest.json` is not for Webpack. It's for you.

Let's say for example that you have a Python [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/) web application and your web pages are built with [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) templates. You could use Webpack to generate all of your static assets, and use the `manifest.json` to resolve the asset generated by Webpack. [This Flask extension](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/manage-your-assets-with-flask-webpack) does just that. This means that in your jinja template you can write this:

```html
<img src="{{ asset_for('images/hamburger.svg') }}" alt="Hamburger">
```

and get this:

```html
<img src="images/hamburger.d2cb0dda3e8313b990e8dcf5e25d2d0f.svg" alt="Hamburger">
```

Another use case would be if you want fine control where the bundles are injected into your templates. For that, have a look at [this example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/custom-insertion-position) in the html-webpack-plugin repo.

Comment: So even if I don't use **WebpackManifestPlugin**, **HTMLWebpackPlugin** will use `manifest` internally when bundling is executed, and **WebpackManifestPlugin** serves the `manifest.json` in favor of the developer, is this correct?